# Highlight text on an image in android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am working on an app in which I have pdf images that contain have text, I need to highlight the text on which user long pressed by his finger, as in pdf reader like repligo and others.I searched a lot but didn't find any relevant way to do it.
Can someone will share the idea to do it or it maybe more helpful if someone can explain via some code or example.

Answer (score 2):

My Friend. 
Even I am also thinking about the same kind of situation. According to me, It can only be done if u know the pixel values of the text . I mean from where it start and at which pixel it ends. Then you have to make a Database for the entire pdf like the Quran Android Application on Market. They simply recognize the device before sending the data from server to client. '
Suppose u r using tablet, then tablet specific pixels are there n if you are using Mobile Device, Then device specific coordinates will come in form of database which can easily be matched by touch. 
Then u can easily find which word or paragraph is going to be selected . Then u can do the selection part by using the object of Path in Canvas. 
Thank You

Comment: Hi Can you please point out a sample application to implement such concept from basic level. Since Quran Android  is no more open source I want to build similar app